# Javascript text manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just starting with js, decided to convert Friendfeed to a fluid app, and as part of that I need to be able to parse some numbers out of a string.

How do I complete this function?

```
function numMessages(text) {

    MAGIC HAPPENS (POSSIBLY THE DARK ART OF THE REGEX)

    return number;
}
```

input would be "Direct Messages (15)"

output would be 15.

Instincts tell me to find the first bracket then find the last bracket, and get the text in between but I don't know how to do that. Second instinct tells me to regex for [0-9], but I don't know how to run regexes in js. Jquery is avaliable already if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the message (aside from the number) always the same? Will it always be the same? What kind of format changes can you imagine happening in the future?

Comment: For now I think that it will be the same, or be redesigned and totally break, so I'm happy with the naive assumption that this is the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>>> 'Direct Messages (15)'.match(/[0-9]+/g);
["15"]
```

Just be careful if you expect more than 1 number to be in the string:

```
>>> 'Direct 19 Messages (15)'.match(/[0-9]+/g);
["19", "15"]
```

If you only wanted the first match, you could remove the `g` flag:

```
>>> 'Direct 19 Messages (15)'.match(/[0-9]+/);
["19"]
```

If you only wanted to match what's between the parentheses

```
>>> 'Direct 19 Messages (15)'.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
["(15)","15"] 
// first index will always be entire match, 2nd index will be captured match
```

As pointed out in the comments, to get the last match:

```
>>> var matches = 'Direct 19 Messages (15)'.match(/[0-9]+/g);
>>> matches[matches.length-1];
"15"
```

Though some boundary checking would also be appropriate. :)

Comment: That's an array, so you probably want to get [0] from match.

Comment: Looking at his example, I think it's most likely he'd want the last number. He could put the answer into an array "arr" and use arr[arr.length-1].

Comment: Thanks Nosredna, I forgot to give that example. Fixed.

Comment: Good. :-) Of course the real danger is that the string he's scanning changes in some unpredictable way. But there's only so much you can do to future-proof the scanning of an alien string.

Comment: @Paolo: great answer.  I added a pattern case, hope you don't mind.

Comment: This sort of answer is why this website is so incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = new RegExp('[0-9]+');
reg.exec('Direct Messages (15)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function numMessages(text) {
  return text.match(/\d+/g);
}
```

This will return all numbers (`\d` is a special character class equivalent to `[0-9]`) from the string. the `/g` makes the regex engine do a **global** search, thereby returning an array of all matches; if you just want one, remove the `/g`. Regardless of if your expression is global or not, `match` returns an array, so you will need to use array notation to get at the element you want.

Note that results from a regular expression match are of type string; if you want numbers, you can use `parseInt` to convert "15" to 15.

Putting that all together, if you just want one number, as it seems to appear from your initial question text:

```
function numMessages(text) {
  return parseInt(text.match(/\d+/)[0]);
}

str = "Direct Messages (15)";
numMessages(str); // 15
```